# Tying the return type of a method in a trait to the type thats implimenting the trait

Tags: generics, methods, rust, traits, self

I have a trait `Vertex` that I want several structs to implement. I want to require a structs that implement the trait to have a method that returns a Vector of that struct. So the implementation would look something like this.

```rust
struct Point {
    // ...
}

impl Vertex for Point {
    fn from_byte_buffer(buffer: &[u8]) -> Vec<Self> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

That way you can call it like `Point::from_byte_buffer(...)`. However I'm lost as to how to write the method signature in the trait. This was my best guess.

```rust
trait Vertex {
    fn from_byte_buffer(buffer: &[u8]) -> Vec<Self>;
}
```

However, this gives me an error,

```
the size for values of type `Self` cannot be known at compilation time
```

which kinda makes sense 'cuz in this context Self is not a concrete type. I thought about doing something like this,

```rust
trait Vertex {
    fn from_byte_buffer<V: Vertex>(buffer: &[u8]) -> Vec<V>;
}
```

but then that's not tied to the concrete type that is implementing the trait. Do I need to use associated types or something?

Comment: You can define the trait like this: `trait Vertex: Sized { ...} `.

Answer (score 2):

All Rust traits have an implicit `?Sized` bound, so:

```rust
trait Trait {}
```

Desugars to:

```rust
trait Trait where Self: ?Sized {}
```

This is done by default so that trait can be cast into trait objects. You can override this default by setting an explicit `Sized` bound on the trait, e.g.

```rust
trait Trait: Sized {}
```

Or optionally setting an explicit `Sized` bound on the specific trait item, e.g.

```rust
trait Trait {
    fn func() where Self: Sized {}
}
```

The benefit of the latter approach is you'll still be able to cast the above trait to a trait object (although you won't be able to call that particular `Sized` method).

Applying the first solution to your example yields:

```rust
trait Vertex: Sized {
    fn from_byte_buffer(buffer: &[u8]) -> Vec<Self>;
}

struct Point;

impl Vertex for Point {
    fn from_byte_buffer(buffer: &[u8]) -> Vec<Self> {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=518db72c16b5315bb6a351c4bc515a98)

Applying the second solution yields:

```rust
trait Vertex {
    fn from_byte_buffer(buffer: &[u8]) -> Vec<Self> where Self: Sized;
}

struct Point;

impl Vertex for Point {
    fn from_byte_buffer(buffer: &[u8]) -> Vec<Self> {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3b1a1fbbef2c55abaf68a31fdcc62846)

Both of which compile and work as you'd expect. The reason why you need to mark `Self` as `Sized` in the first place is because `Vec` can only contain items with sizes known at compile time.

If you'd like to develop a more thorough and in-depth understanding of how sizedness works in Rust I recommend reading [Sizedness in Rust](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/sizedness-in-rust.md) (Disclaimer: I wrote it).

Answer (score 0):

You may bound `Self` to be `Sized`:

```
trait Vertex where Self: Sized {
    fn from_byte_buffer(buffer: &[u8]) -> Vec<Self>;
}
```

Or simply

```
trait Vertex: Sized {
    fn from_byte_buffer(buffer: &[u8]) -> Vec<Self>;
}
```

since `Self` is `Vertex`.

Edit: or using associated types:

```
trait Vertex
where
    <Self as Vertex>::Inner: Sized
{
    type Inner;
    fn from_byte_buffer(buffer: &[u8]) -> Vec<Self::Inner>;
}

struct Point {
}

impl Vertex for Point {
    type Inner = Point;
    fn from_byte_buffer(buffer: &[u8]) -> Vec<Self::Inner> {
        vec![]
    }
}
```